# How to intercept (server side) a non-streaming HTTP WCF request after it is started but before the request payload is uploaded

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have WCF clients that are making some large HTTP Post requests from some potentially slow connections. I want to do some server side work on those requests as soon as I know the URI and QueryString of the request but before the payload actually finishes uploading. The requests are non-streaming.

My understanding is that the AfterReceiveRequest method of IDispatchMessageInspector gets called after the request has been fully received so that doesn't work.

Is this even possible in WCF?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the message would have been received, but you can still operate or replace the the message in the AfterReceiveRequest.

> AfterReceiveRequest is invoked by the dispatcher when a message has
>   been received, processed by the channel stack and assigned to a
>   service, but before it is deserialized and dispatched to an operation.
>   If the incoming message was encrypted, the message is already
>   decrypted when it reaches the message inspector. **The method gets the
>   request message passed as a reference parameter, which allows the
>   message to be inspected, manipulated or replaced as required**.

It seems you'd prefer to do something server side, but you can also  implement the IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest to inspect and operate on the message just before it is sent out to the server.

> BeforeSendRequest is invoked when the message has been composed either
>   by the client application or by the operation formatter. **As with the
>   dispatcher message inspectors, the message can just be inspected or
>   entirely replaced.**

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx)

Comment: This is good but i really need to know the nature of the request (query string, URI, etc) well before the package is uploaded. It cases of large messages on slow connections it could take minutes for the message to upload and that's too late for me .

Comment: Which is why I mentioned you can do it on the client before it is sent to the server.